# Does Visual Basic give Audio Playback priority over other code?

Tags: vb.net, audio, visual-studio-2015

I'm encountering an issue using `My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudiofile", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)`

I need my program to play an audio file to completion, then execute another few lines of code, and then play another audio file. For whatever reason, visual basic seems to give priority to the audio lines of code while ignoring the lines between until the end of the code block. For example:

```
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudio1", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    x.Visible = True
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudio2", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    x.Visible = False
    x.Location = New Point(829, 343)
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudio3", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    x.Visible = True
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("my audio4", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    x.Visible = False
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudio5", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

Executing the following code, a jpeg picture, 'x', is meant to appear after "MyAudio1" plays, then disappear after "MyAudio2", then move, reappear, etc. However, instead of executing in the proper order, all of the audio files will play, one after another, before the 'x' even appears for the first time.

Even just running the first 3 lines:

```
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudio1", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    x.Visible = True
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("myaudio2", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

the picture 'x' will not appear until after both audio files have played.

I would love some feedback as to why this phenomenon is happening, and how to get around it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: VB does not give priority to anything. The OS's multimedia support handles playing the audio. It's hard to say why the code between isn't working for you, because you've not given any information about what x is at all, and you've posted code totally out of any context.

Comment: Call `x.Invalidate()` after changing the visibility to force a repaint of the control.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, Invalidate does not cause a synchronous repaint.  You need to call `Update` to force an immediate repaint after invalidating.  So just call `x.Refresh` that does both.  You should only need that after changing from `Visible=False` to `Visible=True`.

Comment: @TnTinMn as per MSDN [Invalidate does cause a repaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx) **Invalidates a specific region of the control and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.**

Comment: The core issue here is that the OP's code hangs the UI thread, caused by AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete.  No painting occurs until the last sound completes.  Audio.Play is a very simplistic method, it does not support any kind of sequencing while still allowing AudioPlayMode.Background.  A thread would be a workaround.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, and that message is sent to the application's message queue and will not be processed until calling method ends.  Update calls [UpdateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx) that also sends a paint message, but it is sent directly to the window not the application message queue.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it. 

`x.Refresh` worked to force a repaint to the window, but I could not use `x.Visible = False` to make the picture disappear using the same technique. 

Alternatively I used the SoundPlayer function, and it seems to allow for sequencing.